# Integration By Parts w/ Ln

Tags: calculus

Compute $\int \dfrac{1}{x\ln(x^{19})} \,dx$.

Method 1 ($u$-sub): Let $u=\ln(x^{19})$ and $\,du=\dfrac{19}{x}\,dx$. Then,
$$ \int \dfrac{1}{x\ln(x^19)} \,dx = \int \dfrac{1}{19} \dfrac{\,du}{u} = \dfrac{1}{19} \ln|u| = \dfrac{1}{19}\ln|\ln(x^{19})| + C $$

Method 2 (Rewrite then $u$-sub):
$$\int \dfrac{1}{x\ln(x^19)} \,dx = \int \dfrac{1}{19x\ln(x)} \,dx = \dfrac{1}{19} \int \dfrac{1}{x\ln(x)} \,dx$$
Let $u=\ln(x)$ and $\,du=\dfrac{1}{x}\,dx$. Then,
$$ \dfrac{1}{19} \int \dfrac{1}{x\ln(x)} \,dx = \dfrac{1}{19} \int \dfrac{1}{u} \,dx
= \dfrac{1}{19} \ln|u| = \dfrac{1}{19} \ln|ln(x)| + C $$

Why don't the answers match?

Comment: $$\log(\log x^{19}) = \log 19 \log x = \log \log x + \log 19$$ Your two answers differ by a constant, so it can be absorbed by the $+C$

Comment: You are totally right!!!! Thank you

Comment: They are the same just noted that $\ln|19\ln x|=\ln|\ln x|+\ln 19$.